# Javascript Timeout between for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So it's probably some mis-understanding on the best way to use the `setTimeout` method provided by javascript but im having trouble implementing it in a way that makes sense.

Essentially I have an Array with numbers between `1-4` and each number corresponds to a button getting let up.

```
for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        view.renderPane(arr[i]) //All this does is set the .css
```

view.renderPane is pretty simple:(I have a separate function that clears(sets opacity back to .5) it, but if possible i'd like to just put that in here.

```
  renderPane(pane){
    $("."+pane).css("opacity", "1");
    console.log("Activating Pane "+ pane)
  }
```

So I tried setting up a timeout thinking I could call the renderPane within the timeout, but all it did was set up a bunch of timeouts that basically fired off after X seconds (or milliseconds). Is there a way I can call the `renderPane(pane)` function every 1 second (to set up a delay) inside this for loop? or will I need to set up something else?

Comment: you need to call the function every 1 second : have you tried interval

Comment: @NairAthul Will interval prevent the for loop from running? since I would only need to call the `renderPane` function so many times (based on the array length)

Comment: yes interval will trigger every 1 second(as you provide). you can also clear / stop the timer when you want also

Comment: Are you trying to render the panes one after the other with a delay between each? After doing them all, do you want it to "wrap around" to the first pane (and continue indefinitely)?

Comment: No, basically it needs to render then clear (like a second after it renders and lights up the button). Think of like a simon game. the lights flash yellow/red/yellow/blue...etc.. and then stop (which would be my array length which represents the computers moves)

Comment: So you have 4 button which will enable and disable when I start the loop and need to stop after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a loop, just create a function which continuously schedules itself with `setTimeout` until it's done — in this case, it removes an item from the array in each call and stops when the array is empty:

```
(function callee() {
    view.renderPane(arr.shift());
    if (arr.length)
        setTimeout(callee, 1000);
})();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2fwht35d/

There are many other ways to implement this behaviour, but this should give you a good starting point.